# AssemblyInitialize method doesnt run before tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am using MsTest V2 framewrok for my tests.
I have Test automation framework (TAF) project and project with tests.
Tests project inherited from TAF and contains only tests.
In TAF i have a class which contains method which should run before all tests but it doesnt work at all.
By the way BeforeTest method works fine.

```
public class TestBase
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void BeforeClass(TestContext tc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before all tests");
    }
    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before each test");
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class FirstTest : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FailedTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(false,"ASDASDASD");
    }
}
```

If I put "AssemblyInitialize" method to tests projects then it work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

Just put `[TestClass]` onto your `TestBase`:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestBase
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void BeforeClass(TestContext tc)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Before all tests");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Before each test");
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn work because TestBase class and FirstTest class has different assemblies.

Comment: I think i have found the answer. There is a issue in MsTest framewrok https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/143

Comment: I also found it useful to use assertions in the [AssemblyInitialize] and [TestInitialize] methods. If the assertions fail the corresponding tests will not be launched but marked as failing.